# Template ASP.NET with the React template on IIS - error 404

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net

I built and published the application using this instruction: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022
I used two projects: "React" and "API asp.net" Visual Studio templates.

Chose publish ASP.NET Core project to the folder. Moved the application to a local IIS server and created a website.
Before publishing, I corrected the URL of the 'target' parameter to React to the URL of the website. Perhaps there is a wrong action here.

As a result,

- "http://localhost" response with code 404
- "http://localhost/weatherforecast" response 200 with JSON

How to configure the application to run on the IIS server?
I'm trying to find material on this topic, but without results.

Comment: First check the build and release folders on build machine and see what dll are in the folder.  Then check deploy machine to see if same dlls are in the same folder as the executable.  When installing software on a different machine from build you must publish and then run the setup.exe that is created by the publish.  Building a Net/Core app uses windows dlls and the dlls on the deployed machine may need to be updated.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm afraid I don't quite understand you. Is your suggestion really applicable to my problem?

Comment: Absolutely!!!!!